# Deep links for bootstrap tabs

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I am trying to add deep linking for bootstrap tabs. It does add the tab id to the URL on each tab click but when I access the direct link ([www.site.com/tabpage/#tab2](http://www.site.com/tabpage/#tab2)) for the particular tab in a new browser window, it doesn't take me to the second tab. how can I make it work?

I need to get the direct URL to the particular tabs.

Here is the code used

HTML

```
<div class="tab_container">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item mr-4 no-gutter">
                  <a class="nav-link active" href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item mr-4 no-gutter">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item mr-4 no-gutter">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#tab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item mr-4 no-gutter">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#tab4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 4</a></li>
</ul>


<div class="tab-content cisco-extralight p-4 pt-5 no-gutter">
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1">
Tab 1 contenrt
</div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab2">
Tab 2 contenrt

</div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab3">
Tab 3 contenrt

</div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab4">
Tab 4 contenrt

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
//tab deep linking
var url = window.location.href;
  if (url.indexOf("#") > 0){
  var activeTab = url.substring(url.indexOf("#") + 1);
    $('.nav[role="tablist"] a[href="#'+activeTab+'"]').tab('show');
  }

  $('a[role="tab"]').on("click", function() {
    var newUrl;
    const hash = $(this).attr("href");
      newUrl = url.split("#")[0] + hash;
    history.replaceState(null, null, newUrl);
  });
```

Comment: show html code as well.

Comment: `www.site.com/tabpage#tab2`  means i open the page www.site.com/tabpage and go to anchor `tab2`  is it what you want?

Comment: @Frenchy yes exatcly. currently it goes to the default first tab irrespective what is the url

Comment: @Swati added html.

Comment: When does the JS code you have shown execute? Is the BS library already loaded at this point? Does the browser console have anything to say? Where is the _proper_ [mre]?

Comment: Hi , i tested this its working fine can you make working code with that behaviour ?